# I Got stuck with Laravel Starter Kit Breeze with Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix, laravel-vite

## Why Starter Kit of Laravel Breeze Vue is not working with Laravel Framework 8.83.17?

Is it occurring due to conflict of **webpack.mix.js** and **vite.config.js?** Because project has **webpack** by default but when I run **`php artisan breeze:install vue`** and **`npm install`** it added **`vite`** also

I'm using **`MAMP Server`** instead of **`Laravel's local development server`**

> **I did below steps:**

- **Laravel Project**: **`composer create-project laravel/laravel laravue`**

  - Laravel version: **Laravel Framework 8.83.17** checked with **`php artisan --version`**
  - `cd laravue`
- Then **`composer require laravel/breeze --dev`**
- **`php artisan breeze:install vue`**
- **`php artisan migrate`**
- **`npm install`**

### **Outputs:**

When I run **`npm run dev`** then it creates below warning

[image: CMD Output]

**When i run the project i can see only `@vite('resources/js/app.js')` in browser**

[image: Browser Output]

### Should I migrate from [Laravel Mix to Vite](https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/blob/main/UPGRADE.md#:%7E:text=Migrating%20from%20Laravel%20Mix%20to%20Vite)

Comment: you should alter your mamp configuration so that the public folder is the document root

Comment: @Snapey this is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing **`PHP v8.1.0`** and Laravel **`v9.19.0`** it fixed my problem.